# Dreamweaver regex finding and replacing text?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I want to ask how the format regex to change each word like this ?

ex:

```
AAAAAA*BBBBB
Bad*Good
Black*White
ss+bb*cc+gg
```

result:

```
(AAAAAA*BBBBB)
(Bad*Good)
(Black*White)
ss+(bb*cc)+gg
```

thanks, sorry for my english

Answer (score 3):

```
/([a-zA-Z]*\*[a-zA-Z]*)/g
```

and replace with:

```
($1)
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/fP6gN4/2